# UICollectionView not returning all cells

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a custom xib and my aim is to display it like the image below in a collection view:

[image]

I set up my collection view like this:

**Collection View Title**

```
+(id)newTitleView
 {
VideoCollectionViewTitleView* vidcollectionTitleView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProductCollectionViewTitleView" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];

if ([vidcollectionTitleView isKindOfClass:[VideoCollectionViewTitleView class]])
{
    return vidcollectionTitleView;
}
else
{
    return nil;
}
}
```

**Data Source**

```
-(instancetype)initWithVideos:(Videos *)videos
  {
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
   {
    _videos = videos;
   }
return self;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

return _videos.content.count ;

}


-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

Video *video = [self.videos content][indexPath.row];
VideoCollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView  dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:kGENERIC_COLLECTION_CELL_ID forIndexPath:indexPath];


for (int cnt = 0; cnt <[[video youtube]count]; cnt++) {

    NSMutableString *youtubeImageString = [[NSMutableString   alloc]initWithString:kYOUTUBE_IMAGE_URL];

    [youtubeImageString replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"videoId" withString: [video youtube][cnt++] options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, youtubeImageString.length-1)];
    NSLog(@"check the url %@", youtubeImageString);

    [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:youtubeImageString]
                      placeholderImage:nil
                             completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
                                 if (cacheType != SDImageCacheTypeMemory)
                                 {
                                     cell.imageView.alpha = 0.0;
                                     double val = ((double)arc4random()/ARC4RANDOM_MAX)*0.8;
                                     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:val options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
                                         cell.imageView.alpha = 1.0;
                                     } completion:nil];
                                 }

                             }];

    //set labels

    [cell.nameLabel setText:@"Videoooos"];

}

return cell;
}
```

**This is how I add the objects to the data source:**

```
 VideoCollectionViewTitleViewDataSource *dataSource = [[VideoCollectionViewTitleViewDataSource alloc]initWithVideos:self.model.videos];
        [self.collectionViewDataSourceArray addObject:dataSource];
```

And this is the result that I am getting:

[image: result]

When I put a break point on : `[self.collectionViewDataSourceArray addObject:dataSource];` this is what I am getting:

[image: break point]

As you can see there is only item but there are more than one item in my array, any suggestions on what I am doing wrong here would be really appreciated as I am stuck on this.

**Video.Content[ ]Youtube[ ] :**

> [type]: videos
>      [content]: (
>          " \n   [youtube]: (\n       4Cw856cbyNI,\n       GcmEqI9fpYo,\n       L7xR42O825Q,\n       kZem01RQOeQ,\n
>   L7xR42O825Q,\n       \"swgU9Q-8aEA\",\n       \"v_joMRl6wus\",\n
>   tKwSgFo0Dz8,\n       \"Rg2C-9QJmN0\",\n       \"UEW3EYc_aKE\"\n
>   )\n"    )

**Videos Class:**

```
    @interface Videos : JSONModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *title;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *type;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *display;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray <Video> *content;
```

**Video Class**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "JSONModel.h"

@protocol Video @end
@interface Video : JSONModel

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *youtube;

@end
```

Note : I have already looked at : [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191491/using-collectionview-in-uiview-with-xib-file), however it is not useful in my case.

Comment: What is the value of `_videos.content.count` when `numberOfItemsInSection` is called?

Comment: @DonMag "section = 0 " that's what I get when I put a break point there

Comment: No... what is the value of `_videos.content.count`? Is it a valid array of somethings? Or is it an array of `1` object?

Comment: @DonMag It is an array of object and it inherits the youtube array from a different class

Comment: @DonMag I've updated the question

Comment: OK - so what is the value???? Your image shows only **ONE** "box" under the Videos title, which indicates the collection view only has **ONE** item in its datasource which indicates `numberOfItemsInSection` is returning `1` ... which means your array contains only **ONE** element. But the only way to know that is to ***check the value of `_videos.content.count`***

Comment: @DonMag the value is the video id of a youtube video = "L7xR42O825Q"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154453/discussion-between-donmag-and-taha-amini).

Answer (score 0):

1.let cellReuseIdentifier : String = “cellName”.

2.@IBOutlet weak var myCollectionView: UICollectionView?

3.var nibName = UINib(nibName: cellReuseIdentifier, bundle:nil)
        myCollectionView?.register(nibName, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier)

4.let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellReuseIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell